# Problems with Array.Find method with Dates in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, date

I manage an array of Objects like this

[image]

I see that this is the same

[image]

But when I try this

[image]

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/logs/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to do with TypeScript or the **find** method.

If I try to print the result of

```
new Date("2022-10-12T00:00:00") == new Date(2022, 9, 12)
```

I get **false**, so it's normal that the **find** returns **undefined**.

Maybe you should try to compare stringified Dates (using methods such as **toISOString()**) instead of Dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
this.festivos.find(f => new Date(f.fetcha).getTime()==new Date(2022,9,12).getTime())
```

When you compare two Date objects, you fall victim to object reference equality. You could compare their time component instead as illustrated above.

Comment: when I try this I get undefined again